# Undefined method when using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am using devise for my authentication,i tried customizing the users/sign_in route to users/login but i keep getting this error

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new
undefined method `user_session_path' for #<Module:0x651c828>
```

It highlights this line which is in the sign_in view

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

below is my route.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
  post "login", to: "devise/session#new"
end
```

Comment: Please help us to better assist you: edit your question and format it nicely

Comment: Do you really want to set up additional routes (meaning that `/users/sign_in` is still available) or do you just want to change the names of the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to ADD new paths to devise, and you simply want to change the path names, then this is a better option:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: 
  {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

Though - if you're altering the controllers (using your own instead of devise stock controllers) then this doesn't work well.

Platformatec has some really great documentation though, you should pour through it and mix and match to meet your needs.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos